# How to deploy a TP in Sawtooth Test Network?

Tags: python, hyperledger-sawtooth

I'm new to sawtooth and python. I've just read through this [guide](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide.html). I build a [single test node](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html), and I rewirte the [xo_transaction](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-sdk-python/tree/main/examples/xo_python/sawtooth_xo)(just the processor). Could anyone tell me how to deploy it on the test node?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Ranski Can you please add anything what you have yet.

Comment: @Ashishyadav I have build a single sawtooth test node on my ubuntu system following this [guide](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html). I also rewrite the [xo_transaction](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-sdk-python/tree/main/examples/xo_python/sawtooth_xo), but I don't know how to run it on the sawtooth test node.